# How to fetch values in an Excel file and repeat a stored procedure execution more than once?

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Server and I have the following T-SQL script:

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO

DECLARE @var1 NCHAR(2)
DECLARE @var2 DATE
DECLARE @var3 NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @var4 BIT

SET @var1 = val1
SET @var2 = val2
SET @var3 = val3
SET @var4 = val4

BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT a.*
FROM [MyDataBase].[dbo].[MyTable1] a (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [MyDataBase].[dbo].[MyTable2] b (NOLOCK) ON b.id2 = a.id1
WHERE b.Col1 = @var1
ORDER BY a.id1

EXEC [MyDataBase].[obj].[MyStoredProc] 
        @param1=@var1, @param2=@var3, @param3=somevalue, @param4= @var2

SELECT a.*
FROM [MyDataBase].[dbo].[MyTable1] a (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN [MyDataBase].[dbo].[MyTable2] b (NOLOCK) ON b.id2 = a.id1
WHERE b.Col1 = @var1
ORDER BY a.id1

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
--COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Then I have an Excel file with one column and more than 600 lines (each line is an INT).

The goal of the above script is to repeat in the transaction the same stored procedure `[MyStoredProc]` by varying the parameter `@param3`. The parameter `@param3` retrieves values from the Excel file.
This procedure is good when I have a very limited values to put in @param3. For that I can just repeat the same EXEC instruction as possible as I have value like this:

```
EXEC [MyDataBase].[obj].[MyStoredProc] 
        @param1=@var1, @param2=@var3, @param3=somevalue1, @param4= @var2
EXEC [MyDataBase].[obj].[MyStoredProc] 
        @param1=@var1, @param2=@var3, @param3=somevalue2, @param4= @var2
EXEC [MyDataBase].[obj].[MyStoredProc] 
        @param1=@var1, @param2=@var3, @param3=somevalue3, @param4= @var2
...
```

Unfortunately, in my Excel file I have more than 600 values.

So my questions are:

1. How to use my Excel file to be able to fetch value in it ?
2. How can I use a one line `EXEC` instruction (something like a loop while) for the more than 600 values.

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: Stop spamming `NOLOCK`. Do you really understand what it does? If you *really* need (which I doubt) to use `NOLOCK` against *every* table change the isolated of the transaction. [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: I suggest you rewrite the stored procedure to accept a Table Valued Parameter, and do all that it does in bulk

Comment: No modification of the stored procedure is a prerequisite. The SP is intended to add an element to a group. And my need is to be able to repeat in my transaction that operation in a loop, but don't know how.